# Mysql Duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I would like to avoid duplicate entries in DB.

1. In php I check if record exists, before insert takes place.

```
$lead = $CI->db->get_where(db_prefix(). 'leads', ['fbid' => $sender]);
if ($lead->num_rows() == 0) {
    $CI->social_model->create($sender);
}
```

2. In mysql i have UNIQUE parameter set to fbid.

Issue is that sometimes facebook sends identical queries at the same time, and my php check fails because of that reason. I was wondering if there is any way to avoid duplicates on mysql end for the queries that are sent at the same time. (or any other way is welcome)

Comment: Where exactly are the duplicates? When you have the UNIQUE constraint on your DB you should not get any duplicates in your DB.

Comment: @Kartoffelkultur This was my undestanding as well but despite that i have duplicates in my DB in case two similar queires are done at the same time.

Comment: Could you post the (simplified) Create statement of the table including the Unique constraint ? And an example of an duplicate entry ?

Comment: PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `fbid`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `tblleads`(`id`, `fbid`) USING BTREE,

Comment: and the id is Auto Increment correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is, that you have a Unique key over the `fbid` and the `id` column. So when you insert a new Row into the table you have a unique combination of `id` and `fbid`, because when you insert the same data again, you get an updated `id` value, so the constraint is met.

Your constraint should only contain the `fbid`

Or, when you want more than one entry for an `fbid` you should look if you have any other value in the response from api that can be used for the constraint (like a timestamp )

Comment: I see this makes lots of sense, what about PRIMARY KEY should i keep both ?

Comment: This depends, if you have multiple entrys for the same fbid, it could make sense. When you have the need for an id column et all  it could also be enough to just have the id as the primary key. Because when you don't need the id field for unique identification why have it et all ?